# Blender creates screenshot using python script but not when running in background

Tags: python, screenshot, blender

Am I crazy or is there some bug with this feature (using python script with blender running in background) ?

1/ Copy / paste the following code (from screenshot.py) inside Blender (switch to Scripting view) and it will take a screenshot but ...

2/ Call this script from command line : (so you can automatize screenshots while you're modifying the scene with your script(s) ... for your blog, a tutorial, etc.)

```
blender --background --python screenshot.py
```

And it will crash without giving informations about what is "incorrect" in the context

screenshot.py :

```
import os, sys

#FIXME: Blender creates screenshot using python but not when running in background
#
# Same result from Ubuntu stock version (2.76) and from ppa (2.78)
#
# Within Blender : unable to fix this last warning but screenshot is generated !
#
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "/usr/share/blender/2.78/scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_text.py", line 32, in draw
#    text = st.text
#AttributeError: 'SpaceView3D' object has no attribute 'text'
#
# From command line (crash) : blender --background --python screenshot.py
# Unable to determine what's wrong in the context
#
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#(...)
#File "/usr/share/blender/2.78/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 187, in __call__
#    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), C_dict, kw, C_exec, C_undo)
#RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.screen.screenshot.poll() failed, context is incorrect

def screenshot(P_filename, P_path = None):
  import bpy

  L_saveAs = P_filename
  L_saveAs = os.path.join(P_path, L_saveAs) if P_path else os.path.join("/tmp", L_saveAs)
  print("Scene saved in " + L_saveAs)

  #XXX: switching to 3D full view = maximize scene in main window
  #bpy.context.window.screen = bpy.data.screens['3D View Full']
  for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    screen = window.screen
    print("Window : " + str(window.width) + "x" + str(window.height) + ":" + str(window.x) + "," + str(window.y))
    print("Screen : " + str(screen.name) + ", Scene : " + str(screen.scene.name))
    #for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    for area in screen.areas:
      print("Area   : " + str(area.type))
      if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for space in area.spaces:
          print("Space  : " + str(space.type))
          if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            #space.viewport_shade = 'RENDERED'
            for region in area.regions:
              print("Region  : " + str(region.type))
              if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                L_altBpyCtx = {                        # defining alternative context (allowing modifications without altering real one)
                  'area'      : area                   # our 3D View (first found)
                , 'blend_data': bpy.context.blend_data # just to suppress PyContext warning, doesn't seem to have any effect
                #, 'edit_text' : bpy.context.edit_text  # just to suppress PyContext warning, doesn't seem to have any effect
                , 'region'    : None                   # just to suppress PyContext warning, doesn't seem to have any effect
                #, 'scene'     : bpy.context.scene
                , 'scene'     : screen.scene
                , 'space'     : space
                , 'screen'    : window.screen
                #, 'window'    : bpy.context.window     # current window, could also copy context
                , 'window'    : window                 # current window, could also copy context
                }
                bpy.ops.screen.screenshot(L_altBpyCtx, filepath = L_saveAs, full = False)
                break #XXX: limit to the window of the 3D View
            break #XXX: limit to the corresponding space (3D View)
        break #XXX: limit to the first 3D View (area)

screenshot("screenshot.png", ".")
```

3/ By the way, call it without the "--background" argument and it will generate an empty screenshot (size of your window, full of gray). In the meantime, uncomment

```
#bpy.context.window.screen = bpy.data.screens['3D View Full']
```

and/or

```
#space.viewport_shade = 'RENDERED'
```

And you'll see your Blender interface being affected (switching layout of your views from 'Default' to '3D Full View' and/or your viewport shading from 'Solid', by default, to 'Rendered') ... so the script is actually interpreted but it does not generate the screenshot !

No matter what, the problem seems coming from calling Blender with "--python somescript.py" directly from the command line

I'm probably missing something ?! Thanks for your help

Comment: The --background option runs with no UI...so how do you expect to iterate through UI elements to take a screenshot?

Comment: Blender **process** is launched in background with the UI just **not showed** but still it's available (on purpose, so tasks / rendering can be scripted / automated). UI components, even not displayed, are just considered as objects like other ones so you can use / modify / create them or manipulate them with operators like bpy.ops.someObject.doSomething. Try `blender --background --python screenshot.py` and you'll see the script iterating through each components of UI tree (Window > Screen > Scene > Area). By the way, try `blender --python screenshot.py`  and you'll get an "empty" screenshot.

Comment: For a better comprehension / full explanation : [Blender Official tips and tricks](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_tips_and_tricks.html#don-t-use-blender)
This feature could be very useful for people who are interested in controlling (thanks to multiview / step by step screenshots) programmatic modeling / manipulations (using open source software : Blender instead of other limited tools, like OpenScad), let's say in a 3D printing context. Instead of seeing only final result, being able to programmatically take screenshots can **really** help "debugging" !

Comment: from the tips and tricks page:

"scripts that are not interactive it can end up being more efficient not to use Blenders interface at all and instead execute the script on the command line."

the key words are "not interactive" - you can render out to a file, but you can't take a *screen* shot of something that isn't on the screen.  The UI isn't rendered at all.  The Blender *objects* and scene graph are available, but the UI elements are not.  In order for your screenshot to work, you would need to render the UI out to a file, and I don't know of any UIs that work that way.

Comment: Thanks Dale for your help but call the same command line (point 3) **without "--background"**, so you now have a "full" Blender UI running and still screenshot is not doing what is expected ! (while you can see the interface modified by the script itself if you uncomment the lines indicated before). You can even set **Full = True** in **bpy.ops.screen.screenshot** (so **all** the UI should be captured) ... same result ! I'm actually able to render a lot of things from python with blender in background but this approach is limited since you have to render view by view and cannot see selections

Comment: While I should be able to customize the UI to have a multiaxis view a make a screenshot of the full window. By the way, since you seem well understanding the rendering process, I'm quite interested in how you can programmatically render a selection (actually one of my main concern, being able to "see" / check if the selected edge loop is the good one before extrusion), and by "selection" I mean the edges highligthed (selected) before manipulation. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible.  I played around with it a bit and it seems like the python script runs *before* the UI shows.  Try it!  Add `print("DONE!")` right after the call to `bpy.ops.screen.screenshot` and then add `time.delay(5)` after that (of course, `import time` at the top as well).  You will see that the script prints "DONE" (meaning the screenshot is already taken) and then five seconds later the UI will appear.  So, the screenshot script happens before the UI appears, and there doesn't seem to be any way to make the script execute afterwards.

Comment: I've also tried many tests like those ones: delaying script, looking for events with application handlers, using a dummy/empty blend file, etc. That's why I wrote _the problem seems coming from calling Blender with "--python somescript.py" directly from the command line_ I think we can call that **a bug since this feature is not usable because scripts are only interpreted before UI is ready**, and that's probably why the context is incorrect no matter Blender is running in background or not ! Thanks for your help, I'm filling a bug unless you find a workaround, feel free to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer from a Blender guy (thanks sergey). Bottom line : **it's a limitation since all the scripts passed via command line argument are executed at command line processing time, prior to any OpenGL draw is done** !

> The warning is caused by script trying to trick the system and
>   override the context, that context is likely in inconsistent state.
>   When running screenshot from the interface you don't need to override
>   any of the contexts.
>
> All the scripts passed via command line argument are executed at
>   command line processing time, prior to any OpenGL draw is done. The
>   screenshot operator itself is just reading OpenGL buffer,m without
>   doing any actual drawing (it can't draw anything since that'd be
>   unsafe).
>
> When running blender in background mode, there is no window created,
>   which also means there is no OpenGL context. You can;t use screenshot
>   in such configuration.
>
> So thanks for the report, but it's just limitation which can not be
>   easily bypassed.

**Precision** : (since the provided code do not show all the attempts made trying to "trick" Blender)

Sadly, if you are also / still interested in such feature, you'll have to think outside (Blender) box ! Don't waste your time trying to "trick" Blender, like delaying script execution, playing with application handlers, faking script import in a Text editor, etc. ... I've done it for you : it doesn't work, probably for a very similar reason.

Comment: is this still an issue in blender 2.8?